# uppercase A gets trimmed from beginning of ajax response

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

If I make an ajax request and the response starts with uppercase A it gets trimmed. If it starts with lower a or any other uppercase char it's fine.

The ajax script

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "response.php",
  success: function(msg){
    alert(msg);
  }
});
```

PHP

```
<?php echo 'ABC'; ?>
```

The response is BC, if the php code would be 'abc' the response would be abc

Note: I'm running apache2 on ubuntu server with php 5

Comment: this code is exactly what you are using?

Comment: This is a simpler version of the problem. But this makes the same error as if I made a query to a database that returned uppercase A

Comment: be sure that there is something wrong at server printed results...

Comment: before you send back the result of the sql query, print it out to a log file so that you can see the result was correct

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the result from the database, because I can generate the same error with just the code above that has no query.